# No api registered after initializing dataTables

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I wanted to use APIs in dataTables, such like `table.ajax.url().load()` and `table.data()`, after I have initialized it like this:

```
table = $elem.dataTable(options);
```

But no methods like `ajax` or `data` were registered to the `table` variable at all. None of the APIs were registered at all.

Where was the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$elem.DataTable(options);` or `$elem.dataTable(options).api();